# Conditional Expression C# BUG?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I tried a simple conditional expression in C# v7.3 and ran in to following:

```
bool? someBoolean = string.IsNullOrEmpty(*someValue*) ? null : *some condition*;
```

This is a simplified version of my code, but nonetheless this code return the error:

> CS8370  Feature 'recursive patterns' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.

If you replace `null` with e.g. `true` the expression above passes without any error.
Is this a bug in C# 7.3?

Comment: try `(bool?) null`

Comment: FYI that does work in C# 10.

Comment: Yep, can confirm. [.net 6](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O5WdkD) and [c# 7.3](https://dotnetfiddle.net/woz2QK)

Comment: there's simply no common base-type for `null` and `whatever`, so you have to **explicitely** provide any using a cast. That's nothing specific to 7.3, IMHO. The same happens if you would do `var a = somecondition ? new Derived1(): new Derived2()`, where both types derive from some common base.

Comment: Are you using pattern matching in *some condition*? Please include the original expression.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, note that C# 9.0 introduced [Target-Typed Conditional Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-conditional-expression)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes sure, but OP is asking about 7.3, where this was not yet available.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory, and it's not a bug in C#.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're after only exists in C#9 and is called [Target-Typed Conditional Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-conditional-expression):

> Conditional Expression Conversion
> For a conditional expression c ? e1 : e2, when
>
> 1. there is no common type for e1 and e2, or
> 2. for which a common type exists but one of the expressions e1 or e2 has no implicit conversion to that type
>
> we define a new implicit conditional expression
> conversion that permits an implicit conversion from the conditional
> expression to any type T for which there is a
> conversion-from-expression from e1 to T and also from e2 to T. It is
> an error if a conditional expression neither has a common type between
> e1 and e2 nor is subject to a conditional expression conversion.

As there is no common base-type from `null` and `a condition`, you'd get the error in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not a bug but rather design (in)decision  - the code shown has a problem that could be caused by either missing conversion or attempt to use newer feature in code compiled by older compiler. Compiler could have reported both errors but I expect that it would require complicated attempt to parse more code that already known to fail (usually error handling done by attempting to guess code/skip to known point rather that trying to parse anyway).

If you want pure errors for a given version of C# (or any other language) - use the exact version of the compiler - VS 2022 will use C# 10 compiler with features turned off to compile C# 7.x code thus having different error explanations on that line, using C#7/8 compiler will eliminate the second possibility and you get one you expect ("types on two sides of conditional statement don't have common base") .

Answer (score -1):

Just tried this and it worked (.net core 3.1):

```
bool? someBoolean = string.IsNullOrEmpty(null) ? (bool ?)null : false;
```

Comment: @canton7 The above syntax works on older versions too, because of the cast